# Uniqueness of the gradient as defined in Evan's PDEs

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Definition (Cahpter 5,  Evan's PDEs):
Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set.
A function $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentaible at $x\in U$ if there exists a vector $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$u(y)=u(x)+a\cdot (y-x)+o(|x-y|),\quad y\in U.\qquad (1)$$
as $y\rightarrow x.$

Of course (1) is equivalent to

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow x}\frac{|u(y)-u(x)-a\cdot (y-x)|}{y-x}=0.$$

It says that the vector $a$, if it exists, is unique.

How prove that ?

We know that, if $b$ is another gradient of $f$ at $x$
then
$$u(y)=u(x)+b\cdot (y-x)+o(|x-y|),\quad y\in U.\qquad (2)$$
as $y\rightarrow x.$
So, from (1), (2)
$$(a-b)\cdot (x-y)=o(|x-y|)$$
as $y\rightarrow x.$ Which implies
$$(a-b)\cdot e_{x-y}=o(1)\qquad \text{(equivalently)}
\qquad \lim_{y\rightarrow x}{|(a-b)\cdot e_{x-y}|}=0$$
where $e_{x-y}$ denotes the unit vector in the direction $x-y$. How deduce that $a=b$ from here ?

Note: There is a related question here
[How to prove the uniqueness of the gradient?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3792094/how-to-prove-the-uniqueness-of-the-gradient)
But I'd like to use the definition of differentiability in Evan's as it is without invoking equivalence of definitions.

Comment: (The name is Evans, not Evan.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}$. Note that by letting $y=x+te_i$, in (1), we have as $t\to 0$,
\begin{align}
u(x+te_i)&=u(x)+a\cdot (te_i)+o(|t|)\\
&=u(x)+ta_i
+o(|t|)
\end{align}
i.e $a_i=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{u(x+te_i)-u(x)}{t}$ (and if you really want to be precise about why I was able to change the limits $y\to x$ to $t\to 0$, just write out what the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of limits are). This shows $a$ is unique because each of its components $a_i$ is uniquely determined by $u$ (since the RHS only depends on $u$, rather than $a$). Or another way of phrasing the uniqueness is that $a_i=b_i=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{u(x+te_i)-u(x)}{t}$, and thus $a=b$.

As a bonus, you may recognize this as the definition of the partial derivative of $u$ at $x$, so this also shows that $a_i=(\partial_iu)(x)$.

Comment: Why there is no loss of generality in letting $y=x+t e_i$ ?

Comment: I mean how does your argument work if we let $y_i=x_i+te_i$ in which case we lose no generality ?

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is. Do you agree that $a_i=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{u(x+te_i)-u(x)}{t}$? Also, $y_i=x_i+te_i$ is nonsense. $y_i,x_i\in\Bbb{R}$, and $e_i\in\Bbb{R}^n$ so their addition is not well-defined.

Comment: The issue is we can assume that $y=x+\xi$ for some vector $\xi$, so we can always assume that $y_i=x_i+{\xi}_{i} e_i$, ${\xi}_{i}\in \mathbb{R}$, that is fine. But the difference of two vectors does not necessarily lie on (in the same direction as) a coordinate axis, i.e., it is not true for any two vectors $x,y$ that $y=x+t e_{i}$.

Comment: @Medo so that's what I'm saying fix the $i^{th}$ direction, and restrict your attention to points $y\in U$ which lie along the $i^{th}$ coordinate axis. i.e look at all the points $y\in U_i:= U\cap \{x+te_i\,|\,t\in\Bbb{R}\}$. For such points $y$, we also have $u(y)=u(x)+a\cdot (y-x)+o(|y-x|)$. By letting $y\to x$ as $y$ is restricted to this line $U_i$, you obtain information about what the number $a_i$ is (and you thus get the explicit limit expression $a_i=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{u(x+te_i)-u(x)}{t}$). If you do this for all $i\in\{1,\dots n\}$, then you uniquely determine $a_1,\dots, a_n$.

Comment: THe thing is the statement "$u(y)=u(x)+a\cdot (y-x)+o(|y-x|)$, as $y\in U$ and $y\to x$" contains a lot of information. What I am doing is trying to slowly extract the information contained in this statement. I am doing so by going through one by one along each direction and looking at what happens as I restrict my attention to $y\in U_1, y\to x$. After that I look at what happens as $y\in U_2, y\to x$ and so on, $y\in U_n, y\to x$. Each stage tells me precisely what $a_1$ is, then what $a_2$ is etc.

Comment: Okay. I got it. You are arguing as follows: since  the statement "$u(y)-u(x)=a\cdot (y-x)+o(|x-y|)$ as $y\rightarrow x$" for EVERY $y\in U$, $y\rightarrow x$ then, given $x$, we are entitled to look only at the points $y$ such that $x-y=t e_i$.